# SQL PIVOT on a variable amount of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following data on a MSSQL Server:

```
Item No_    Unit Of Measure     Qty Per Base UoM    Rounding Precision
000001      PIECE               1                   1.0
000001      PALLET              100                 1.0
000001      BOX                 12                  1.0
000002      KG                  1                   1.0
000002      TON                 1000                0.001
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
Item No_    UoM1    Qty pb UoM1 RP1     UoM2    Qty pb UoM2     RP2     UoM3    Qty pb UoM3 RP3
000001      PIECE   1           1.0     PALLET  100             1.0     BOX     12          1.0
000002      KG      1           1.0     TON     1000            0.0001  NULL    NULL        NULL
```

I tried achieving this using the PIVOT operator but it does not seem te be correct.

What is the correct way to achieve my desired output?

Comment: My attempt is not really worth showing. I did not even got a working query without errors. The PIVOT operator just doen't seem to be the correct way, however my SQL knowledge is limited so i have no idea what the correct way would be.

Comment: So basically you want us to do your job. Probably someone will do, but for learning first I will try do research and ask specific question.

Comment: I agree, And i am not asking for a complete solution. If someone just could push me into the right direction would be probably enough. I did several hours of research already. Found alot of examples but none that came close enough to my exact problem. As a last resort, i am asking here on StackOverflow

Comment: What's the rule here? Why PIECE goes to UoM1 and TON goes UoM2?

Comment: There is no rule. The order of the UoM's does not matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For trully generic solution you need to use Dynamic-SQL.** 
But you say you want starting point, so I give you one. You can use:

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375425)**

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item_No_ ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn
   FROM #mytable
)
select Item_No_,
  max(case when rn = 1 then Unit_Of_Measure end) UoM1,
  max(case when rn = 1 then Qty_Per_Base_UoM end) [Qty pb UoM1],
  max(case when rn = 1 then Rounding_Precision end) RP1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then Unit_Of_Measure end) UoM2,
  max(case when rn = 2 then Qty_Per_Base_UoM end) [Qty pb UoM2],
  max(case when rn = 2 then Rounding_Precision end) RP2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then Unit_Of_Measure end) UoM3,
  max(case when rn = 3 then Qty_Per_Base_UoM end) [Qty pb UoM3],
  max(case when rn = 3 then Rounding_Precision end) RP3,
  max(case when rn = 4 then Unit_Of_Measure end) UoM4,
  max(case when rn = 4 then Qty_Per_Base_UoM end) [Qty pb UoM4],
  max(case when rn = 4 then Rounding_Precision end) RP4
from cte
group by Item_No_;
```

The point is that if your number of units is known in advance you can create hardcoded columns from `1 .. n`.

For more info search *Dynamic Pivot multiple columns*. It is achievable, but first try to crack this solution.

Comment: I just look for the max number of units so i can adjust my query. Thanks or the example